# So many red underlines for no reasons (C#),(vscode)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

Hey fellow stack overflow surfers!
This bit of code is causing me trouble,

```cs
using System;


namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

but in vscode,

[So many red underlines!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aej0x.png)

It runs perfectly using "dotnet run"

is it my problem, or vscode's??

Comment: I tried pasting this code into vscode, and it gave me none of these dreaded red underlines. Could you provide a list of the plugins you're using, as well as an example of what some of these red underlines are about?

Comment: Hm do you have the C# for Visual Studio Code extension installed? As in https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp&ssr=false#overview

Comment: why do you have `obj` in your SCM tracking? What are the 33 PROBLEMS you have?

Comment: I use the c# extesion for vscode.